# How to plot using ggplot2 a numeric variable against categorical variable after applying a summary function to numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data, 'bankdata', is something like this:

```
job    duration
a       20
b       30
a       40
b       25
c       29
c       34
```

I want to draw a bar plot with the three jobs ('a', 'b', 'c') on x-axis and mean(duration) being the height of each bar on y-axis using ggplot2. How do I do it? I have tried various alternatives but to no avail.

```
ggplot(data=bankdata,mapping = aes(x=job,y=duration)) +  stat_function(fun=mean,geom="bar")
ggplot(data=bankdata,mapping = aes(x=job,y=mean(duration))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: I think you got most of the way there, the main thing is to use `fun.y` to only apply your `stat_function` to duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_summary` should give you what you're looking for.

```
ggplot(bankdata, aes(x=job, y=duration)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the aesthetics by using below code:

```
ggplot(data=bankdata,mapping = aes(x=job,y=duration)) +  
       stat_function(fun=mean,geom="bar") + 
       scale_fill_manual( values = c("red","yellow","blue","orange","green","purple"))
```